# ¿Por qué me sigue direccionando para la ruta /home en Laravel sin esta ya no existe?

Tags: laravel-5, login, seguridad

Estoy trabajando con Laravel 5.5, cuando inicié mi proyecto usé el comando `make:auth` para crear la parte de seguridad de mi sitio.

Normalmente se crea una ruta de ejemplo "/home", pero posteriormente la removí de mi archivo de rutas `web.php`. El comportamiento por defecto antes de eliminarla era que si estaba logueado e intentaba acceder a la ruta `/login`, automáticamente me redireccionaba para /home, sin embargo al remover esta ruta, el no la encuentra y me lanza una excepción.

No quiero que siga redireccionando hacia esa ubicación, ni quiero crear o cambiar mi ruta "/" por "/home". ¿Qué puedo hacer para evitar este comportamiento?

En `Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController.php`

```
protected $redirectTo = '/';
```

En `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers.php`

```
protected function sendLoginResponse(Request $request)
{
    $request->session()->regenerate();

    $this->clearLoginAttempts($request);

    return $this->authenticated($request, $this->guard()->user())
            ?: redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
}

public function logout(Request $request)
{
    $this->guard()->logout();

    $request->session()->invalidate();
    $request->session()->flush();
    $request->flush();

    return redirect($this->redirectTo);
}
```

Comment: Pude mas o menos solucionarlo agregando esto al archivo routes/web.php
Route::get('/home', function(){
   return redirect('/');
});  **pero no es la mejor manera**

Comment: Yo tenia tu mismo error, lo único que hice fue hacer una búsqueda avanzada de /home en mi editor de texto (sublime) y reemplazar por /  y me funcionó correctamente jejeje

Comment: Trabajo con PHPStorm e hice lo que me recomendastes encontré unas cuantas referencias pero solo 3 que eran de archivos de php, lo cambié pero nada se mantiene. Si supieras más o menos en cuales archivos hicistes los cambios, te lo agradeceria

Answer (score 0):

Puedes configurar la ruta de tu controlador HomeController ejemplo:

`Route::get('/inicio', 'HomeController@index')->name('inicio');`

Luego configura una acción para que siempre te envíe a donde desees

`Route::get('/home', function () {
    return redirect()->action('HomeController@index');
});`

Recuerda que debes tener configurado tu LogiController de la siguiente manera

`protected $redirectTo = '/inicio';`

Answer (score 0):

amigos esta respuesta va para todas aquellas personas que le pase lo mismo no es necesario ninguna redireccion el archivo lo consigues en config -> fortify -> modificas la ruta del home